# Why does Mojo::Message::Response return an empty body?

Tags: perl, http, mojolicious

I am trying to access the body of a `Mojo::Message::Response` object with `$res->body` but I get an empty string.

If I do `$res->to_string` I get the following

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=DE/ST=Bayern/L=xxxxx/O=xxxx/CN=oa.xxxxx.com
X-BEServer: DEHEREMEX52
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=Blah, Inc./OU=See www.blah.net/legal-terms/OU=(c) 2012 Blah, Inc. - for authorized use only/CN=Blah Certification Authority - L1K
Persistent-Auth: true
X-CalculatedBETarget: blah.blah.blah.biz
Client-Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 05:50:47 GMT
Client-Response-Num: 3
Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2017 05:50:47 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Client-SSL-Warning: Peer certificate not verified
X-DiagInfo: DEHEREMEX52
Set-Cookie: ClientId=PZCOBXREXHBNPYAIEA; expires=Fri, 13-Jul-2018 05:50:48 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=565bea08845b4a9fb053ac5e7e60e16e; expires=Fri, 13-Jul-2018 05:50:47 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=S-1-5-21-1409082233-362288127-725345543-9215=u56Lnp2ejJqByp3MyMvMmsbSmc3Jx9LLnsid0sfImZvSx8qZns/Omp7Nyc3PgYHNz87I0s/H0s7Nq8/KxcrPxcvH; expires=Sat, 12-Aug-2017 05:50:48 GMT; path=/ews; secure; HttpOnly
X-FEServer: BLAHBLAX
Content-Length: 0
Client-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Request-Id: ea3453f9-83b0-42fa-88a0-3d16ac35a6a6
Client-Peer: 87.237.216.20:443
Cache-Control: private
Connection: Keep-Alive
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
```

and if I do `print dump $res->content` I get the following (parts omitted for clarity), with the content I want clearly in `buffer`:

```
do {
  my $a = bless({
    asset           => bless({ auto_upgrade => 1, start_range => 0 }, "Mojo::Asset::Memory"),
    auto_decompress => 1,
    auto_relax      => 1,
    auto_upgrade    => 1,
    body            => 2,
    buffer          => "the content I want is here and there is a lot of it",
    events          => { read => [sub { ... }] },
    ...
    header_size     => 1363,
    headers         => bless({
    ...
    }, "Mojo::Headers"),
    pre_buffer      => "",
    raw_size        => 3973,
    read            => 'fix',
    real_size       => 2610,
    size            => 0,
    state           => "finished",
  }, "Mojo::Content::Single");
  $a->{read} = $a->{events}{read}[0];
  $a;
}
```

However `$res->body` returns an empty string. I suspect it has to do with `size`, `real_size` and the content being chunked, but what is it?

Doing the same with `curl -v` returns these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Fri, 14 Jul 2017 06:04:11 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Cache-Control: private
request-id: ac058f09-a121-4d27-bbdf-ea7505e1ff33
Set-Cookie: ClientId=FLKNCOOKUWTCVQKSQTZQ; expires=Sat, 14-Jul-2018 06:04:12 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-CalculatedBETarget: cihiuz.blah.xxx.biz
X-DiagInfo: XXXXXXXXXXX
X-BEServer: XXXXXXXXXXX
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=f5013e861b6949539169122ab1af6046; expires=Sat, 14-Jul-2018 06:04:12 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=S-1-5-21-1409082233-362288127-725345543-9215=u56Lnp2ejJqByp3MyMvMmsbSmc3Jx9LLnsid0sfImZvSx8qZns/Omp7Nyc3PgYHNz87I0s/H0s7Mq8/Jxc/Lxc7N; expires=Sun, 13-Aug-2017 06:04:12 GMT; path=/ews; secure; HttpOnly
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: XXXXXXXXXXX
```

**ADDED**

I found I can get to the content with `$res->content->leftovers` - is that the proper way?

Comment: This looks more like you access a buggy server which does not properly implement HTTP. Leftovers are data sent by the server after the proper HTTP response is done. If you provide the URL one might have a look what's really going on there.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I can't provide a URL, sorry. Company server, confidentiality etc. etc. It's an Exchange Web Service - in case it helps. Any suggestions to work around this? It seems to work OK with LWP::UserAgent, but I wanted to only use Mojo::UserAgent in the app.

Comment: Could you provide the full original response header, maybe with `curl -v`? The one you show is changed by Mojo already. Also, which version of Mojolicious you are using?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - I added the `curl -v` header; I was using 7.10, and upgrading to 7.36 gives me the same results

Comment: Nothing strange in these headers so it must be something in the response body or that the server reacts differently to the request from Mojo. At least I cannot find out what causes the problem without having access to the original HTTP traffic (i.e. after SSL unwrapping but before any processing by the HTTP client) to reproduce the problem. And without this I also cannot find a workaround.